# Fetching from Core Data and display in UITableView with custom cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data

I have a UITableView with a custom cell:

title, label, text

These are 3 elements of UITextView, now I have an entity in my core data:

[image]

I want to put title, in title, the date in label and introText in text:

I did this:

```
    do{
        var request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Actualites")
        let count  = try context.count(for: request)
        if (count == 0) {
            REST().SaveArticles(limit: 5, limitstart: 0, catid: 6, key: "xxx", context: context)
        } else {
            var actualites  = [Actualites]()
            actualites = try context.fetch(request) as! [Actualites]


            let cell:ActuTblCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! ActuTblCell

            for actualites in actualites {

                print(actualites.title)

            }
        }
    }catch{
        print(error)
    }
```

I can get the titles in the loop, but how to display the data ? Do I have to create 3 arrays ?

EDIT:
I think I have to do a loop here ?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ActuTblCell


    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"

    cell.titleActuCell.text = actualites[indexPath.row].title
    cell.dateActuCell.text = formatter.string(from: actualites[indexPath.row].created! as Date)
    cell.descriptionActuCell.text = actualites[indexPath.row].introText

    return cell
}
```

Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view controller keep an array of `Actualites`: `var actualites = [Actualites]()`. Then your `else` block would look like this:

```
else {
    actualites = try context.fetch(request) as! [Actualites]
    tableview.reloadData()
}
```

You should implement the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol to return the number of cells based on the `actualites` array, and in the `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` you get the actuality for every cell by this statement: `let actuality = actualites[indexPath.row]` and display in the appropriate cell.

Comment: sorry finally it's ok :)